Charger issue after hibernate or running somethigng using NVIDIA GPU
my machine is presenting a very weird issue which only sometimes happens and also, stops happening suddenly too;
Today, I left my machine and pressed window+L to lock the screen... When I back, I did note that the laptop was hibernating; After log-in on this again, I did note that the battery was in 45% and was not charging... I tried disconnecting and connecting again the charger plug from the laptop, and it didn't work, but if I remove the charger from the wall dock and connect again, then the charger starts charging again, but only for a few time and stops again.
It's not the first time it happens, few weeks ago the same happened, but it was when I was running a LLM model on my local GPU Nvidia (535.171.04);
I don't have any idea on how to solve this issue and I did a lot of searches, but I didn't find any solution for this; Does someone know what's happening and how to solve this problem?
EDIT1: My OS version: Ubuntu 22.04

Are you even using Ubuntu?  Which supported release? Please [edit] your Question to add new information.  Do not use Add Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Sure... We are in the askUBUNTU forum hehehe I did set the OS version in the flags; Anyway, I have edited it and added the OS info explicitly
